# Understanding the roots of homomorphism and homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition

I understand the formal (i.e. mathematical) definitions of the terms "homomorphism" and "homeomorphism" **as they relate to functions**, but I am curious as to the origin of these terms. I don't know Greek (it's *all* Greek to me), but "morph", I believe means "form", while both and "homo" and "homeo" mean two objects are the "same" (in some sense). *So understanding the distinction between these terms by solely examining the words themselves is somewhat baffling to me.*

If we talk about a function mapping some set $A$ (endowed with some binary operation "+") to some set $B$ (with a binary operation "*"), then I interpret a "homomorphism" to be a function which preserves the "form" in the sense that it preserves the *structure* of the operations, i.e. for all $x,y$ in $A$, $f(x+y) = f(x)*f(y)$.

I think of a function which is a homeomorphism as a function which preserves "form" in the sense that both $f$ and its inverse preserves the basic fundamental topological properties of sets, i.e. both $f$ and its inverse map open sets to open sets.

I am just curious if someone with a better understanding of these terms can shed some light on why I should think of "homomorphism" and "homeomorphism" as being different in some sense (other than falling back on the fact that they are just definitions) and if so, how one can see this distinction from the words themselves.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: I think homomorphism already existed and the topologists wanted to avoid confusion (especially for topological groups, where we could have both notions) and chose a similar but different name. One would have to go to the original papers or books.

Comment: @Henno: According to the OED, *homeomorphism* is a borrowing of French *homéomorphisme*, which was first used by  H. Poincaré in 1895, in Jrnl. de l'École polytechn. I. 7. The first English citation is from Veblen, 1918: ‘A (1–1) continuous transformation of a complex into itself or another complex is called, following Poincaré, a homeomorphism.’

Comment: Greek homos or homeos (I'm not sure):the same. Greek morphos: shape.